# Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

In my code, two errors appearing in the title and content in the HTML file. I want to input posts item and show them in the list.

> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.
> Property 'content' does not exist on type 'never'.

```html
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <ngb-panel id="toggle-1" title="{{post.title}}" >
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      {{post.content}}
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

this is the ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {


content ="";
  etitle = "";
  elist = "";
  posts = [];

  onaddlist() {
    const posts = {
      title: this.etitle,
      content: this.elist
    };

  }



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: can u share the posts array details?

Comment: How is `posts` declared in your component?

Comment: Try to change your `posts` declaration to `posts: any[] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

There is only one usage of the `title` property: `post.title`. That means that one of the `posts` array elements is `never`. `never` is an indicator of the unreachable block. I'm sure if you add proper typings for `this.posts`, the compiler would indicate an issue.